# Saving a PyNeural model to disk

Tags: python, joblib

I trained a model using [PyNeural](https://github.com/tburmeister/pyneural).

How do I save this trained model?
I tried `pickle` and `sklearn.externals.joblib` but did not work.
As the later, said `TypeError: can't pickle NeuralNet objects`

Comment: What have you tried? `joblib.dump(clf, ’clfname.pkl’)` this should work idealy.

Comment: Any more information than *"did not work"*? Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: It says `TypeError: can't pickle NeuralNet objects`

Comment: Do you have a small reproduce-able example?

Comment: PyNeural seems to be a very young and minimalistic library, it may simply not support that yet. You can either submit an issue on GitHub or switch to a more mature NN library (say, Keras).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Author of PyNeural here. The easiest thing to do is call the

```
NeuralNet.get_params()
```

method on your NeuralNet object. This will return a tuple consisting of the model parameters. You should be able to pickle and un-pickle this tuple. To load the parameters into a new model, instantiate a new NeuralNet object with the same size and number of layers and then call

```
NeuralNet.set_params(params)
```

where 'params' is the tuple you saved.

Hope you are enjoying using PyNeural!